# How to get value from a tag without attribute in xml java

Tags: java, android, xml

I am parsing xml in java.

`<Pht name="Here is the text we need">`

We can get above value using `parser.getAttributeValue(null,"name");`

`<Pht>Here is the text we need<Pht>`

but how we can we get the value here. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Using [XmlPullParser.nextText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser#nextText()) method.

```
String content = parser.nextText();
```